# Jquery on click button reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the  following script:

**HTML**

```
<form class="trial_form" id="trial_form" >
   <input type="text" value="TRIAL DATA PLEASE ALERT" id="trial_data" name="trial_data" class="trial_data"/>
   <input type="submit" name="trial_submit" id="trial_submit" class="trial_submit" value="Validate Data"/>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#trial_submit').click(function () {
  alert('CLICKED!!!!');
  alert('Alert!!');
  var bla = $('#trial_data').val();
  alert(bla);
});
```

When I click on the `Validate Data` button, the  page responds with an alert and then reloads the  page passing the information from the test field with it in the following format:

```
http://enunua.com/emarps/main.php?trial_data=TRIAL+DATA+PLEASE+ALERT&trial_submit=Validate+Data
```

How can I prevent the reload of the page?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return false` in event handler to stop form submission.

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$('#trial_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop form submission

    alert('CLICKED!!!!');
    alert('Alert!!');
    var bla = $('#trial_data').val();
    alert(bla);
});
```

Using `return false`:

```
$('#trial_submit').click(function(e) {
    alert('CLICKED!!!!');
    alert('Alert!!');
    var bla = $('#trial_data').val();
    alert(bla);

    return false; // Stop form submission
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **event.preventDefault()**. It is used to prevents the default action and trigger your event

```
$('#trial_submit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('CLICKED!!!!');
    alert('Alert!!');
    var bla = $('#trial_data').val();
    alert(bla);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#trial_submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
            alert('CLICKED!!!!');
            alert('Alert!!');
            var bla = $('#trial_data').val();
            alert(bla);
        });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/wLrfqvss/11/)

Answer (score 0):

> use attr `onsubmit` in form tag.

`<form class="trial_form" id="trial_form" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" value="TRIAL DATA PLEASE ALERT" id="trial_data" name="trial_data" class="trial_data"/>
   <input type="submit" name="trial_submit" id="trial_submit" class="trial_submit" value="Validate Data"/>
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

using return false

```
$('#trial_submit').click(function () {
  alert('CLICKED!!!!');
  alert('Alert!!');
  var bla = $('#trial_data').val();
  alert(bla);

  return false;
});
```